# Accessing DbContext in Middleware in ASP.NET 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I wrote my custom middleware which I add in

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    //...
    app.UseAutologin();
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
       //...
```

So it is the last middleware before the Mvc comes into play.

In my middleware's `Invoke` method I want to (indirectly) access the `DbContext`.

```
 public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
  {
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.User.Identity.Name))
     {
        var applicationContext = _serviceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>();
        var signInManager = _serviceProvider.GetService<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>>();
        var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(_options.UserName, _options.Password, true, false);
     }

     await _next(context);
  }
```

Nearly every time I get the following exception:

> `InvalidOperationException`: An attempt was made to use the context
>   while it is being configured. A `DbContext` instance cannot be used
>   inside `OnConfiguring` since it is still being configured at this point.

Now this is clearly raised by the `PasswordSignInAsync` method. But how can I ensure that the model was created before doing such things?

Maybe I was not entirely clear: I don't want to use the `DbContext` myself - the `PasswordSignInAsync` uses it when verifying the user and password.

Comment: I have the some error. Did u found a correction please.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 17):

What if you inject the `ApplicationDbContext` and `SignInManager<ApplicationUser>` through the `Invoke` method:

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, ApplicationDbContext applicationContext, SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.User.Identity.Name))
    {
        var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(_options.UserName, _options.Password, true, false);
    }

    await _next(context);
}
```

This way you the services are resolved from the correct scope. I notice you don't actually use the `ApplicationDbContext` anywhere, just the `SignInManager`. Do you really need it?

Comment: How will I pass this db context from the caller ? something like app.UseMyMiddleware(dbcontext) ?

Comment: You don't need to do that, it's already in.

Answer (score 9):

This error is likely occurring because any middleware acts as a singleton. You have to avoid using member variables in your middleware. Feel free to inject into the Task Invoke, but don't store the inject value into a member object.

See: [Saving HttpContext Instance in Middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38854690/httpcontext-net-core-saving-instance-in-middleware), 
     [Calling services in Middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37142227/calling-service-repository-methods-in-asp-net-core-middleware?rq=1)

I was able to get around this myself, by creating a class that I could then pass into other methods in my middleware:

```
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, IMetaService metaService)
    {
            var middler = new Middler
            {
                Context = context,
                MetaService = metaService
            };

            DoSomething(middler);
    }
```

Comment: That perfectly answers why I had problems randomly after days or weeks of my app running

Answer (score 5):

Just by this:-

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    var dbContext = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ClinicDbContext>();

    await _next(context);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the simple solution that works great for my use case.
I created a simple method I can call from anywhere in the application to easily get the database context:

```
public class UtilsApp
{
  public static MyDbContext GetDbContext()
  {
    DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext> opts =
        new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext();
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(Program.MyDbConnectionString); // see connection string below
    
    return new MyDbContext(opts.Options);
  }
}
```

Then, to use it anywhere in the application:

```
MyDbContext dbContext = UtilsApp.GetDbContext();
```

I set `Program.MyDbConnectionString` (a `public static string` field) from within `Startup.ConfigureServices()` (which is a callback that is called from within `Program.Main()` via `CreateHostBuilder(args).Build()`).  That way I can use that connection string anywhere in the application without having to repeatedly retrieve it from `appsettings.json` or an environment variable.

Comment: just to explain the downvote...  this is not a good pattern.  you are working against the Dependency Injection patterns of asp.net core.  almost anywhere you want to use a DbContext, it should be injected via constructor or parameter injection.  this includes the Startup.Configure method, middleware, controllers, pages, components, etc...

Comment: @burton, could you possibly share a link to a post, tutorial, or anything that shows it being "injected via constructor or parameter injection"?

Comment: DI Overview:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Can't find an article/doc on action method parameter injection, but you can use the [FromServices] attribute on an action method parameter to inject a service in a controller action method.

Comment: and I should have said "contructor, property or parameter injection".

Comment: Thank you, @burton !  I look forward to "injecting" the knowledge into my brain later this week! :)