# How to inject a repo or service in a middleware in a clean way?

Tags: go, design-patterns, web-applications, middleware

I'm currently working on a web application and implementing a user authentication system using middleware in Go. I'm wondering what the best way is to inject a repository or service in a middleware for user authentication.

The reason I want to do this is because I want to use a repository's method for every user authentication. However, I'm not sure if it's clean to inject a repository or service in a middleware.

Does anyone have any suggestions or best practices for how to do this in a clean and maintainable way?

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37142227/calling-service-repository-methods-in-asp-net-core-middleware) question on Stackoverflow but it seems to be related to C# and not necessarily a design issue.

Thanks in advance for your insights.

Comment: Use a closure that has the repository as your middleware

Comment: Thank you for reaching @BurakSerdar. Just to be sure, you mean I must be defining a local variable of the repository in my middleware and use that in that scope am I write? I'm not much familiar with the term closure and have just searched and read some stuff about it.

Comment: Not exactly. You probably have a configured instance of the repository. Use that variable from that parent scope.

Comment: Are you implementing a middleware or using an existing one? Your question would be better if it contained some code...

Comment: @jub0bs I am using an existing one. btw the service/repo mentioned are being used as service and repo in other places. copy pasting the code here would duplicate the code

Comment: @jub0bs It is not much about code though. my question is more about design and implementation if needed in go. but rather more, I want to know if this is a good approach.

Comment: @MateenBagheri Sure, but it would be easier to have a discussion around some example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are maybe more than a hundred ways to answer to your question, but I'll try to make an answer based on my experiences.
First, if I understood your question, you need to know **how to inject a repository on a middleware** then after, to know if it's **a good practice**.

About your **first point**:

```golang
type AuthenticationRepository interface {
    GetApiKey(location string) (string, error)
}

func AuthorizationMiddleware(authRepo AuthenticationRepository) gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        // Get the location and key from headers
        location := c.GetHeader("Host")
        apiKey := c.GetHeader("Key")

        // Use the repository to get the API key from location
        expectedKey, err := authRepo.GetApiKey(location)
        if err != nil {
            log.Errorf("Unexpected error when trying to get api key: %v", err)
            c.AbortWithStatus(http.StatusServiceUnavailable)
            return
        }

        if expectedKey != apiKey {
            c.AbortWithStatus(http.StatusUnauthorized)
            return
        }

        // Call the next handler
        c.Next()
    }
}
```

With this basic example, you can do what you need on your repository.

Now about your **second point**, is it a good practice to do that? If you have only few users or services, **yes**, you will not have problems.
But, if you want to have a scalable infrastructure with a lot of users: **no, this is not a good practice**.

**Why?** Because all your services must retrieve information from your repository. So you are introducing a SPOF and a lot of latency on all your endpoints.
You can do some caching, but it will be hard to manage if you have a large amount of users.

To handle this, you will need to know the difference between **authentication** and **authorization**: **authentication** verifies the identity of a user or service, and **authorization** determines their access rights.

So, for example, you can **authenticate** a user with his *username/password* (or a service with his *client_id/client_secret*), then, after authentication your authorization service will provide a **JWT token**. This token is signed and can be verified by any service that have the corresponding **public key**. So you don't need to reach a specific service/storage from a repository on every request, because with this **public key**, you can authorize access requests (depending on additional verified token claims).

Some documentation about JWT and flow to get it:

- https://auth0.com/docs/secure/tokens/json-web-tokens
- https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/which-oauth-2-0-flow-should-i-use

So, all of that depend on the volume of users :)

Comment: Thank you for your complete and concise answer.