# HttpContext .NET core saving instance in Middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2

Is it safe to store an instance of HttpContext in a middleware?

Example:

```
public class TestMiddleware
{        
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;    
    private HttpContext context;
    public TestMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)        
    {
        try
        {
            this.context = context;
```

I would like to use it in other private methods to work on it, so I can either pass it around as parameter to those function or use it as shown in the example.

But is it thread safe?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> But is it thread safe?

No it's not, because middleware are necessarily singletons. If you store a specific `HttpContext` in a shared field, it will be potentially reused during another request (which would be terrible).

Comment: What makes you think "middlewares are necessarily singletons"?

Comment: @haim770 they are instantiated during startup and added to the request pipeline, which is immutable: https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions/Extensions/UseMiddlewareExtensions.cs#L43-L94

Comment: @haim770 if you don't trust me, it's easy to confirm: create a custom middleware and put a breakpoint in its constructor. You'll see it's only invoked once, at startup.

Comment: I'm aware to the fact that the middleware type would only be instantiated once. I'm not sure you can guarantee a singleton-style lifetime though.

Comment: Hem. An object that is always instantiated once and is shared across requests is a singleton by definition.

Comment: I guess you're right. It's just that the term "singleton" usually refer to the pattern, not to the lifetime of an object.

Comment: .NET Core framework refer to singleton as the single shared instance, as in AddSingleton method for dependency injection. I know this does not quite match with the old "singleton" where any second instance of the class is restricted, but I guess the meaning of the word just becomes broader now.

Comment: The best way to put it is that as instantiated and used by the request pipeline, the middleware is a singleton.  You could make your own instances of it for other things, but these won't be involved in the request pipeline.

Comment: @KévinChalet, I agree with you with the part of the middleware being a singleton, but the Invoke method is going to be called individually for each request, as the HttpContext is being injected through parameters shouldn't we get a new instance of it for each request?